# Is There a better way to optimize my directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

my code is working, but i'm wondering if there is a better way to improve it.

I have a modal dialog in AngularJS, that i select multiple users.

Openig the modal:

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/common/partials/modal-users.html',
            controller: 'ModalUsersController',
            size: 'lg',
            scope: $scope,
            resolve: {
                users: function () {
                    return $scope.users;
                }
            }
        });
};
```

This is my partial to modal:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Available Users</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body users-list">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
            <user-item
                name="user.name"
                email="user.email"
                file="user.file.sizes.sm || avatarDefault"
                add="add(user.id)"
            ></user-item>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a ng-click="close()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">({{totalSelected}}) Close</a>
</div>
```

The item "user-item" is gonna be very common in my code, because of that, i created a directive for it:

```
.directive('userItem', [function () {
    var d = {};
    d.restrict = 'E';
    d.replace = true;
    d.templateUrl = '/common/partials/user-item.html';
    d.scope = {
        name: '=',
        email: '=',
        file: '=',
        add: '&'
    };

    d.link = function (scope, element) {
        element.on('click', function () {
            element.toggleClass('active');
        });
    };

    return d;
}]);
```

userItem template:

```
<div class="user-item" ng-click="add(user.id)">
    <div class="profile-photo">
        <img ng-src="{{file}}" alt="" class="img-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="infos">
        <strong>{{name}}</strong><br>
        {{email}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and my modal controller:

```
// Modal Controller
.controller('ModalUsersController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'users',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, users) {
        $scope.users = users;
        $scope.totalSelected = 0;
        var selected = [];

        $scope.add = function (id) {
            var finded = false;

            // add or remove the userID
            for (var i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0 && !finded; i--) {
                if(selected[i] === id) {
                    // remove
                    selected.splice(i, 1);
                    finded = true;
                }
            }

            // if doesn't exist element in array
            if(!finded) {
                selected.push(id);
            }

            $scope.totalSelected = selected.length;
        };

        $scope.close = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss();
        };
    }
]);
```

Simplifying this, when the modal is open, i can selected the users, in the directive, the link function toggle the active class to the element.
My modal controller controls the users and save them in an array to use later.

I'm confusing about using logic in my controller and in the link function too. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me, is there any particular problem you are having with it? Any particular problem you are trying to solve? Why do you think it might need to be optimized?

Comment: Hi @KevinB, no, this code works, but i created this topic just for discuss if there is a better way to interact between directive and controller. I'm using the logic in controller and inside the link function, but i think this is the better way. I started in angularjs a feel days ago, because of that, i'm trying to read other opinions. Thanks!